# There is already 'controllers' bean method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package = "mvc"/>
    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "dataSource" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name = "driverClassName" value = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name = "username" value = ""/>
        <property name = "password" value = ""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "jdbcTemplate" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "dao" class = "mvc.dao.DAOImpl">
        <property name = "template" ref = "jdbcTemplate"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

For using REST i need `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`. But after adding it to dispatcher-servlet.xml I'm getting "There is already 'controllers' bean method".
Controllers class here http://collabedit.com/hfrv8
DAOimpl class here http://collabedit.com/dms4s
Full stack trace here http://collabedit.com/f7ux9
Where problem could be?

Comment: @Reimeus, here it is http://collabedit.com/dms4s

Comment: When asking about an error, don't paraphrase it. Post the exact and complete error stack trace.

Comment: That needs to be in the question itself.

Comment: @JBNizet, okay, thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, problem was in several methods of Controllers class with the same annotation @RequestMapping("/viewAll1"). After commenting all of them, error disappeared